# Dove tailing questions about accepting language

Tags: turing-machines

$L = \{M | \text { M is a TM and there exist some string w that contains five 1's such that M halts}\}$

Where $\Sigma =\{0,1\}$

let $w_1, w_2, \cdots, \in \Sigma^*$ be an effective enumeration. We give a TM $R$ that recognizes $L$

```
R = "On input <M>
    for s = 1 to infinity:
        for i = 1 to s
            run M on input w_i for s steps
            if M halts on w_i within s steps then
                accept
```

Can I assume $M$ knows to halt only if there are five $1$'s? Or do I need another if statement such as in line 4

```
if M halts on w_i within s steps then
    if w_i.count("1") is 5 then
        accept
```

Comment: A Turing machine does what you tell it to do. No more no less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing some machine $R$ that recognizes $L$ is enough to prove that $L$ is recognizable, however, you have yet shown $R$ recognizes $L$.

Formally, you must show:

- $M \in L \Rightarrow  R $ accepts $M$
- $M \notin L \Rightarrow  R $ does not accept $M$, but not necessarily halts.

---

Let $S_i$ be all strings in $\Sigma ^*$ of length exactly $i$. It is clear, for any $i$ that is finite, $S_i$ is also finite.

Let $S_i^*$ be a subset of $S_i$, where every $s \in S_i ^*$ contains exactly five $1$'s.

$R$ is a machine that given input $M$:

1. for $i=5...\infty$
2. for $s$ in $S_5^* \cup S_6^* \cup \dots \cup S_i^*$

   simulate $s$ on $M$ for $i$ steps. If $M$ halts in $i$ steps or less, finish and accept. Otherwise continue.

Suppose $M \in L $ (and we will show $R$ accepts $M$):
 There exists $w^*$ of length $k$ that contains five $1's$ and $M$ halts on $w^*$ in $r$ steps.

Since $S_i^*$ is finite, $S_5^* \cup S_6^* \cup \dots \cup S_k^*$ is also finite (finite union of finite subsets), so $R$ simulates $w^*$ on $M$. Now if $r \leq k$ then $M$ halts and $R$ accepts $M$.

If $r > k$ then surely $w^* \in S_5^* \cup S_6^* \cup \dots \cup S_r^*$, hence at $i=r$ $M$ will halt on $w^*$ and $R$ will accept.

The second step is very simple; if $M \notin L$ then no such $w$ with five $1's$ exists such that $M$ halts on it, and $R$ will run indefinitely.